# Can open some avi files in open cv but others fail to open

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

Im working on a project which needs to read avi and mp4 files,,i downloaded a project form git https://github.com/andrewssobral/simple_vehicle_counting

```
CvCapture *capture = 0;
  capture = cvCaptureFromFile("v6_(new)/video.avi");

  //capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  if(!capture){
    std::cerr << "Cannot open video!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
```

ive notices that only some videos ,i got 10 sample videos out of which i can read only 2 all others return NULL

Any one have idea whats happening,im using openCv 2.4.1 and VS13

UPDATE:i can open a webcam and stream video without any problems

Thank you

Comment: If you can play several of them then the problem is with the rest of the files.

Comment: what codecs are active in the video files?

Comment: ive put Klite codec and placed opencv_ffmpeg.dll in source folders,,and i can play all videos in opencv V3.0 using VideoCapture